# WPF Linq Binding join-qry to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, binding, datagrid

I have the following query:

```
var qry = from itemA in db.TableA 
          join itemB in db.TableB on itemA.ID equals itemB.ID  
          join itemC in db.ItemC on itemA.ID equals itemC.ID  
          select new { itemC, itemA, itemB};
```

If I now bind the query to the Datagrid like this:

```
dgTest.ItemsSource = qry;
```

and configure the Datagrid's TextColumn like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgTest" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test" Binding="{Binding TableA.Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The column is empty...
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you set the `DataContext` of your `DataGrid`? Is `TableA` a property of your `DataContext`? Does the object you are using as a data context implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to mention that. The Question is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an implicitly typed variable for your databinding.

Let's assume your object `TableA`, `TableB` and `TableC` look like this:

```
public class TableA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TableB
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class TableC
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Now you need to create a concrete class rather than using an implicit type as you are doing in your `select new {` statement.

So for example:

```
public class MyConcreteClass
{
    public TableA TableA { get; set; }
    public TableB TableB { get; set; }
    public TableC TableC { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, the class where you have your LINQ query should look something like this:

```
public class MyDataSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Database db;

    public MyDataSource()
    {
        db = new Database()
        {
            TableA = new List<TableA> 
            {
                new TableA { ID = 1, Name = "Hello world!" }
            },
            TableB = new List<TableB>
            {
                new TableB { ID = 1 }
            },
            TableC = new List<TableC>
            {
                new TableC { ID = 1 },
                new TableC { ID = 2 }
            }
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public IEnumerable<MyConcreteClass> MyConcreteClass
    {
        get { return this.MyQuery(); }
    }

    private IEnumerable<MyConcreteClass> MyQuery()
    {
        var qry = from itemA in db.TableA
                  join itemB in db.TableB on itemA.ID equals itemB.ID
                  join itemC in db.TableC on itemA.ID equals itemC.ID
                  select new MyConcreteClass
                  {
                      TableA = itemA,
                      TableB = itemB,
                      TableC = itemC
                  };

        return qry.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

With the `Database` class looking to something like that:

```
public class Database
{
    public IEnumerable<TableA> TableA { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TableB> TableB { get; set;  }
    public IEnumerable<TableC> TableC { get; set;  }
}
```

and set the `ItemsSource` property of your `DataGrid` to `{Binding MyConcreteClass}`.

The most important points are:

- You can only bind to a property. You can't databind to a field or a method.
- You cannot bind to an implicit type.

Don't forget to have your view-model implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if required and to use `ObservableCollection`s wherever required too.

Comment: The Problem is: I'm using LinqToEntities and the classes are already created by Linq. I need that join qry to be able to add columns of 3 tables into one data grid...

Comment: Whether you create a view in your DB that holds column info you need and you add it to your entities just like a table. Or you need to create a custom object like the `MyConcreteClass` and handle changes to this object to reflect them to your entities. My answer is just a general answer, you need to adapt it to your code. Just keep in mind you can't bind to implicit types.

Comment: Created a class that holds the 3 classes created by Linq. Works like a charm! Thank you!